# Do the 2011 MacBook Pros support a user-installed SSD in place of the HD

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

On the iMac there is some thermal sensor that connects to the hard drive and makes this a bit tricky since non-Apple SSDs don't have that feature.  Is this true for the 2011 MacBook Pros?

Comment: Until someone actually has one to check, it would be hard to say. However on the 2010 MacBook Pro there isn't one that I am aware of. I swapped the drives out in mine without any issues.

Comment: I also have the 2010 MacBook Pro and swapped out the HD with an SSD. No problems.

Comment: I have two followup questions: 

1) Will TRIM work out-of-box or does this require a first-party drive?
2) Does the OS install any differently to an SSD or can I mirror my existing drive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I replaced the stock 500GB 5400rpm hard drive in my Early 2011 Mac Book Pro [(MacBook Pro 8,2)](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.0-15-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html) with a [120GB OWC Mercury Electra 6G SSD](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Mercury_6G/) a few weeks ago. There was no thermal sensor attached to the stock drive. So far the replacement has worked fine, no issues at all.

[Hardware Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/HardwareMonitor.html) application reports the temperature of the SSD, so the computer must be properly polling the internal temp sensor in the drive (over the SATA interface,) and/or there may be a permanent sensor attached near the drive on the inside of the MacBook Pro's case. (But not actually attached to the drive.)

Screen capture of output from Hardware Monitor:
[image: Screenshot of output from Hardware Monitor app]

There was no difference in the software install process (vs. a regular hard drive.) In fact, I used 2 external cases (and a 3rd, separate, bootable drive) to do a block copy from the original 500GB to the new 120GB SSD. No issues.

About TRIM support:
The drive itself is capable of it (See "TRIM Support" at the bottom of the [specs page for this drive.](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Mercury_Electra_6G)), however, Mac OS X 10.8.2 does not support TRIM *for this drive, at this time*.  The drive vendor OWC [says you don't need TRIM anyway](http://blog.macsales.com/11051-to-trim-or-not-to-trim-owc-has-the-answer) because SandForce's firmware makes it unnecessary or even counterproductive. I agree with their explanation.

Screen cap from my System Profiler:

[image]

### As another data point on SSDs -- I had a 60GB OWC Mercury 3G SSD in a 2009 Mac Mini for about 3 years, never had any problems with it whatsoever.

2013-04-30 UPDATE -- I had some firmware problems with the new 120 GB OWC Mercury 6G drive. The drive would not be recognized at system startup time without doing multiple (10 or more) PRAM & SMC resets. Finally it would "catch on" & then start up and run fine for weeks. Eventually it stopped responding altogether.  (OWC had suggested that I apply a firmware update, but I wasn't able to do this because I don't have a working DVD reader / writer.)

I am returning the drive to OWC for a warranty replacement. It always pays to BACK UP YOUR DATA every single day, or even several times a day.

Comment: A most excellent report. Having people share what works and how they know it makes this a great place for technical answers. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, Crucial and other SSD manufacturers have a component finder on their websites that help you get the correct RAM, SSD, etc. that work on your particular MBP.

Comment: Update as of 2013-03-19 -- continued reliable operation with the OWC SSD, no problems.

Comment: Update 2013-04-30 -- firmware problems, returning the drive under warranty. ALWAYS back up your data, every day.

Comment: Update 2013-10-10 -- drive replaced under warranty in mid-May 2013, and moved it into a new 2012 Mac Mini 2.6Ghz core i7. Running fine, no problems since the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have the correct screwdriver(s) for internal access you can replace the HDD with an SSD.

I apologize for not catching the full question.

Folks at [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Unibody-Early-2011-Teardown/4990/1) did a teardown of the 15" and there is no thermal sensor attached the HDD.

Comment: The question is does it have some thermal sensor that won't be connected so the fans will always be off or always on.

Comment: @BrianCarlton, the thermal-sensor issue is addressed in detail in my answer, above.