# Is it possible to upgrade the SSD in a 2011 model Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, ssd

I have a 2011 model MacbookPro (MacBookPro8,2) which came with a 128GB SSD.  I would like to upgrade the SSD to a larger size without voiding my AppleCare.

- Is it possible to upgrade the SSD at all?  I have heard rumours that they are soldered in after 2010, and are not replaceable.
- My city and country (Tallinn, Estonia) has no official Apple stores that I know of, but does have Apple-authorised resellers.  Are they the appropriate place to get this done?  I've replaced a hard disk on an older model MBP myself, but my current laptop is still within the warranty period.

*This seems like a fairly common question on SO, but all questions I found are for older models or for iMacs, not MBPs.  Perhaps this should be migrated to a community wiki where the question can be updated for all models of Mac?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your questions:

- *Is it possible to upgrade the SSD at all? I have heard rumours that they are soldered in after 2010, and are not replaceable.*

  Yes, it should be possible, [others](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1284046) have done it. This video (How to Upgrade/Replace the Hard Drive in the 2011 15" MacBook Pro) shows the procedure (just for information, I understand you don't want to void your AppleCare warranty): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5opqLFOvh3M.
- *My city and country (Tallinn, Estonia) has no official Apple stores that I know of, but does have Apple-authorised resellers. Are they the appropriate place to get this done?*

  Yes, I'd definitely go to an Apple authorized reseller. I could find Premium resellers in Tallinn (see https://locate.apple.com/ee/et/sales/?pt=all&lat=59.43696079999999&lon=24.75357459999998):

  ```
  IM ARVUTID IDEAL TALLINN
  NARVA MNT. STREET 7, PK 34
  TALLINN EE-10117

  IM ARVUTID SOLARIS
  ESTONIA PST. 9
  TALLINN 10143

  IDEAL KRISTIINE
  KRISTIINE 45
  TALLINN 10615
  ```

  [image]

  You can select another country/language from https://locate.apple.com/country (though I used the trick explained here http://forums.ilounge.com/lounge/224663-where-can-i-buy-apple-products-sweden-finland.html).

Comment: Thanks, Jaume.  I knew about the ones in Kristiine and Solaris, but not the others.  Is there a difference between an 'Authorised' reseller and a 'Premium' reseller?

Comment: I could find this in the "Find Locations" page, "Apple Premium Resellers have been recognized by Apple for providing superior customer service with a focus on Apple solutions, service and support." So they are authorized resellers with a superior service.

Answer (score 2):

Your model should contain an SSD in the same form factor as a standard hard drive. So it should be able to be upgraded to a wide variety of SSD drives.

An Apple Authorized shop should be able to upgrade the drive and transfer your data without voiding the warranty. Apple retain stores only repair broken hardware, they do not  perform upgrade service.

Answer (score 1):

I made a very similar upgrade recently (same model, MacBook Pro 8,2) with good results. Performed the work myself without any problems.

See details in my answer to another similar post:

[Do the 2011 MacBook Pros support a user-installed SSD in place of the HD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9085/do-the-2011-macbook-pros-support-a-user-installed-ssd-in-place-of-the-hd/82648#82648)