# reinstall OS on a new HDD

Tags: macbook-pro, install

I was given a MBP that needs some repairs. Aparently the hard drive is fried so I was planning to replace it with a new one.

Is there a way to download a disk to re install the OS after I get a new HDD in it?
If there is how does licensing work? I am used to windows computers where the Key is on the bottom of the machine. I don't see a key of any kind.
I'm also not sure what version of OSX it should be running.

Comment: which is the model of this MBP?

Comment: Model is A1278.

Comment: MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.5 13" Mid-2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just install the new hard drive and if you have a connection to the internet when you first boot up you can download Mac OS X directly from apple.  If you hold the <kbd>alt</kbd> key while the machine is booting it will take you directly to Internet Recovery.

Some features like iPhoto will be missing from this "free" version however they are very cheap and easy to install afterwards via the app store.

This process was tested on a 2011 MBP, also because you have to download the entire OS the process is quite lengthy.

Comment: Thanks! That's very useful. I'll test it, and mark the answer following.

Comment: Happy to change my answer and help you along the way. It would be useful to know what type of hardware you have?  What model of MBP is it?

Comment: Could I pick up any HDD as a replacement as long as it's a sata 2.5? or SSD? I'd like to purchase a big one from a local computer store to save money. Apple HDD's are pricey!

Comment: Model is A1278.

Comment: I've used these guys before: http://www.macmemory.com/collections/internal-laptop-hard-drives, it will need to be a 2.5, can be SSD if  you like, but that depends on how you use the computer.

Comment: I don't know that much about SSD, I would suggest you read some of the posts here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/9085/10733 however if you want to install an SSD I think you could do it in the HDD bay or via a bracket in the DVD bay: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/74495/10733

Comment: When I checked your model at : http://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=A1278, it shows 12 different possible models which one are you running?

Comment: MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.5 13" Mid-2012

Comment: Jump on chat, I am there now, if you want more info. Your laptop is newer than mine.